# Best way to render custom live tiles in the BackgroundTask (C#) with WP8.1 Universal app?

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8.1

I'm in the process of re-writing my app to the Universal App model, optimized for Windows (Phone) 8.1.

I created my BackgroundTask (C#) that fetches some data from external sources, and the last step is to render a custom .PNG that can be used as a tile.

Previously, for Windows Phone 7.x and 8.0, I used a third party app called  [TCD.Controls.LiveTiles.Light](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Manage-LiveTiles-on-71-AND-d9091d2b) that helps you converting XAML UserControls to .PNGs. This worked flawlessly, but it seems it have some compatibility issues with the Universal App model.

Now I was wondering - what is the best way to create .PNGs in the BackgroundTask?

I read about the C++ implementation of [XamlRenderingBackgroundTask and RenderTargetBitmap](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df)  but as I have not knowledge about C++, and my current task is already in C# I want to use C#.

Kind regards,
Niels Laute

Comment: Just do what they do in the C++ example, only in C#. :) I've tested it and it seems to work okay. I don't think the memory or CPU time are a problem (they weren't when I tested it).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but found this example of rendering a PNG in C#.  I found this on https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/43295c90-43e8-4b08-8a25-958a1c3d0a0b/explanation-on-windowsuixamlmediaxamlrenderingbackgroundtask?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Graphics.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;

namespace BackgroundTask
{
    public sealed class AppTileUpdater : XamlRenderingBackgroundTask
    {
        protected override void OnRun(Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnRun called!");
            UpdateTileAsync(_deferral);
        }

        private async Task<string> ReadFile()
        {
            var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("customTile.xml");
            string szCustomTileXML = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
            return szCustomTileXML;
        }
        private async void UpdateTileAsync(BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral)
        {

            var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
            var file = await folder.GetFileAsync("customTile.xml");
            string szCustomTileXML = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);

            Border tile = XamlReader.Load(szCustomTileXML) as Border;

            if (null != tile)
            {
                tile.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Orange);
                Grid grid = tile.Child as Grid;
                TextBlock text = grid.FindName("Timestamp") as TextBlock;
                text.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
                text = grid.FindName("TimeZone") as TextBlock;
                text.Text = TimeZoneInfo.Local.DisplayName;

                Image logo = grid.FindName("LogoImage") as Image;
                var img = new BitmapImage() { CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None };
                img.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/acorn.png");

                RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap();
                await rtb.RenderAsync(tile, 150, 150);
                IBuffer pixels = await rtb.GetPixelsAsync();
                DataReader dReader = Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader.FromBuffer(pixels);
                byte[] data = new byte[pixels.Length];
                dReader.ReadBytes(data);

                var outputFile = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.CreateFileAsync("UpdatedLiveTile.png", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                var outputStream = await outputFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                BitmapEncoder enc = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, outputStream);
                enc.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied, (uint)rtb.PixelWidth, (uint)rtb.PixelHeight, 96,96, data);
                await enc.FlushAsync();                
            }
            var TileMgr = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
            TileMgr.Clear();
            var tileTemplate = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent(TileTemplateType.TileSquare150x150Image);
            var tileImageAttributes = tileTemplate.GetElementsByTagName("image");
            XmlElement tmp = tileImageAttributes[0] as XmlElement;
            tmp.SetAttribute("src", "UpdatedLiveTile.png");
            var notification = new TileNotification(tileTemplate);
            TileMgr.Update(notification);
            deferral.Complete();
        }

        public void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Run called!");
            OnRun(taskInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the most effective way is to use Win2D Framework and draw bitmap step by step. This approach will keep your resources free.

Comment: Any examples on how to do this?